# Microsoft App Center: How get list of users with session duration?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, analytics, ms-app-analytics

In the [Microsoft App Center](https://appcenter.ms), I need to get a list of users who have spent the most time in the game. However, I did not see App Center providing information about individual users and receiving them.
One of the similar functionalities that I saw was Session Duration, which looks like this

[image]

To display the duration of a session, I send event tracking, and, as I understand it, the session duration is calculated as the addition of the time between these events.

This is my TrackEvent method:

[image]

**Questions:**

1. How can I see more detailed information about my players and the
   duration of their play?
2. Is this possible with the Microsoft App Center?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding "session duration", https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/analytics/faq#session-duration-is-unknown-why says:

"A session is defined as the time from the app coming to foreground to the last event before going to the background. If no custom events are identified within 5 minutes in a session, the session will not be counted."

Looks like application should send at least one event per 5 min, other-ways session duration go to "unknown" state. You can add smt like "ping" event to check this statement.